# How to tell Spring Security that my service class automatically has the "ROLE_ADMIN" and can access secured methods?

Tags: spring, spring-security

I have a web app build with Java and Spring MVC using Spring Security.

My services methods are locked down with security something like this ...

```
public interface UserService {

  @PreAuthorize("hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')")
  public Integer createUser(String username, String password) throws Exception;

}

public interface ConfigurationService {

  @PreAuthorize("hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')")
  public Integer createConfiguration(ConfigurationDTO configurationDTO) throws Exception;

}
```

It all works fine.  Users cannot access this functionality unless they are logged in as a user with "ROLE_ADMIN".

However ... the first time my application starts up (before any user is logged in), I want the application to set things up with default users and default configurations.

I have a service something like this that gets run on start up ...

```
public class MainAppService {

   public void initialize() throws Exception {

     // if first time app is run then set things up
     userService.createUser("admin", "defaultpassword"); 
     configurationService.createConfiguration(myDefaultConfigutation);
     // and so on ...
   }
}
```

The problem is, the calls to 'createUser' and 'createConfiguration' fail with "Access Denied" errors because there is no user logged in.

Is there a way to tell Spring Security that my MainAppService class automatically has the "ROLE_ADMIN" and can access all of those secured methods?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question with my "workaround" solution.

I moved the implementation of "create" to a new "private commonCreate".  Then I have the security-protected "create" call the new "commonCreate".  And I add a new NOT-security-protected "internalCreate" which also calls commonCreate.

So my WebController methods continue to use the security-protected "create" and my internal services use the "internalCreate".

This worked.  But if anyone has a cleaner solution, please let me know.

Example ...

```
public interface UserService {

    @PreAuthorize("hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')")
    public Integer createUser(String username, String password) throws Exception;

    public Integer internalCreateUser(String username, String password) throws Exception;

}

public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService {

    // is protected by Spring Security
    public Integer createUser(String username, String password)  throws Exception {
        return commonCreateUser(username, password);

    // is not protected by Spring Security
    public Integer internalCreateUser(String username, String password) throws Exception {
        return commonCreateUser(username, password);
    }

    private Integer commonCreateUser(String username, String password) throws Exception {
        /* do the creation of the user */
    }
}


public class MainAppService {

   @Autowired
   private UserService userService;

   public void initialize() throws Exception {

       // if first time app is run then set things up
       // bypassing Spring Security
       userService.internalCreateUser("admin", "defaultpassword"); 
       // and so on ...
   }
}
```

If anyone has a better solution, please post an answer!